# Fill up white space in R Plots

Tags: r, plot, space, margins, par

How does one get rid of white space when plotting in R as in the example below?

[image]

I would like to do this because when I want to multiple plots on a page it looks terrible.

I'm using the par function in the following way:

```
par(mfrow=c(5,3),mai=rep(0,4), omi=rep(0,4))
pie3D(c(4,2,2,3,6,3),main="example")
pie3D(c(4,2,2,3,6,3),main="example")
...
pie3D(c(4,2,2,3,6,3),main="example") #do this 15 times. In my real work, it's 15 different pie charts.
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Can you please give a reproducible example < http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 > ? (I will refrain from snarking about 3D perspective pie charts ...)

Comment: Got it. I'm new to the community and appreciate any constructive criticism in my posts.

Comment: There is a nice summary here of Cleveland's empirical research that shows why pie charts are a poor choice: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart In brief, they are difficult to read accurately and quickly. For the problem with 3D, see Tufte on chartjunk, start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartjunk

Comment: @BenBolker I think the vertical white space is here for a good reason; as the viewer moves towards a top perspective, the pies will appear closer to each other (try tilting your screen). @ NewNameStat Joke aside, please do read those comments on why one should avoid 3D pie charts (and such colors, for that matter).

Comment: What is a better way to quickly plot percentages? A bar plot puts too much emphasis on the mode in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `pie3D` overwrites your margins to `c(4,4,4,4)`.

You can set margins in  `?pie3D`:

```
library("plotrix")
par(mfrow=c(5,3))
for (i in 1:15) pie3D(c(4,2,2,3,6,3),main="example", mar=c(0,0,1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Using the `pty='m'` argument will also help to reduce the whitespace on the sides. I think it would be a little tricky to remove the whitespace at the bottom, however.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the response of the previous friend can change the size of the pie with radius and reduce the white space.

```
library("plotrix")
par(mfrow=c(5,3))
for (i in 1:15){pie3D(c(4,2,2,3,6,3),radius = 2,main="example", mar=c(0,0,1,0))}
```